# Wordpress Fatal error after update 4.0?

Tags: wordpress

I have this wordpress: www.verticalvideo.pt

And yesterday, I updated all the plugins, and then updated core to 4.0 (I checked if plugins could handle 4.0 before).

Everything seemed to went fine, even added some 'Posts'.

Today, the site gives me this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_category_id() in
>   /home/vertical/public_html/wp/wp-content/themes/VideoTheme/VideoThemeRes/index.php
>   on line 6

Is this because of wordpress update? Did the function 'get_category_id()' changed name?

PS: I ran UpdraftPlus Backup, but it's failing in restore backups -_-

Comment: A side note...you should really consider fixing the file permissions on your site. As things are now, anyone is able to traverse all of your directories.

Comment: can u help me on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error points out, `get_category_id()` isn't a valid WordPress function.

You'll need to use [get_cat_ID()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_cat_ID) instead.

The only way this could have worked before is if that custom function was defined in **functions.php** or a plugin that was updated.

Comment: Thanks, that helped, but now I'm having this: 

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function ds_get_excerpt() in /home/vertical/public_html/wp/wp-content/themes/VideoTheme/VideoThemeRes/index.php on line 55`

Comment: That's a completely different question. Please close up this one, and ask another, if you're unable to debug line 55 of **index.php**.

Comment: Ok, I changed it to get_the_excerpt and it's working now. Thanks guys!